# Visual code : how to show only the followed files

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, gitignore

In Visual Code, when I click on the Git button I get the list of files, is there a way of filtering the view, i.e not showing for example the file marked with "u"?

Comment: Why down votes, if it that stupid, tell me why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is supported right now. I found an open feature request asking for this exact same thing: [#3918](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3918)

There is also a related feature request asking for a search box: [#11208](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/11208)

Comment: Ok thanks, I didn't think it could be an issue so didn't go to github